# Multiple GoogleMap javascript get calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, get

I'm iterating over a list of "users" and calling a script so it generates a set of 3 googlemaps per user. When I inspect the "Network", the $.get call only seems to have been called for the last user, but all the scripts are loaded within the HTML for each unique user.

"item in elder" are elements rendered by jade, where elders is an array of usernames. I'm using node.js express.

```
if(elders)
  h2 Your Elders
  for item in elders
    h3= item
    script(async='', type='text/javascript').
        var username = "#{item}";
        var loadMap = function(){
            $.get(username+'/getGeoData/', function(data){
                //geofence configuration
                console.log("get request for: " +username)
                var geofences = {};
                geofences['test'] = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(data.gfLat,data.gfLon),
                  radius: data.gfRadius * 1000
                };
                //map options: centered @ current location
                var current_lat = data.mostRecentLocation.latitude;
                var current_lon = data.mostRecentLocation.longitude;
                var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(current_lat,current_lon);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 9,
                    center: currentLocation
                };
                //initialize 3 maps
                var maps = [];
                var cm = 'current_map_'+username;
                var string_cm = String(cm);
                var current_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("current_map_"+"#{item}"),
                    myOptions);
                maps.push(current_map);
                var daily_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("daily_map_"+"#{item}"),
                    myOptions);
                maps.push(daily_map);
                var weekly_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("weekly_map_"+"#{item}"),
                    myOptions);
                maps.push(weekly_map);
                //set current location marker
                for (var m = 0; m < maps.length; m++ ){
                    var location_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: currentLocation,
                        map: maps[m]
                    });
                    for ( var gf in geofences ){
                      var geofenceOptions = {
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        map: maps[m],
                        center: geofences[gf].center,
                        radius: geofences[gf].radius
                      };
                      geofenceCircle = new google.maps.Circle(geofenceOptions);
                    }
                }
                //daily/weekly location path
                var dailyPathPoints = [];
                var weeklyPathPoints = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++){
                    var latitude = data.locations[i].latitude;
                    var longitude = data.locations[i].longitude;
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    //if timestamp within week, add to week array
                    dailyPathPoints.push(point);
                    //if timestamp within day, add to daily array
                    weeklyPathPoints.push(point);
                }
                var dailyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: dailyPathPoints,
                  geodesic: true,
                  strokeColor: '#009ED9',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight: 2
                });
                dailyPath.setMap(daily_map);
                var weeklyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: dailyPathPoints,
                  geodesic: true,
                  strokeColor: '#009ED9',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight: 2
                });
                weeklyPath.setMap(weekly_map);
                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(current_map, 'resize');
                    google.maps.event.trigger(daily_map, 'resize');
                    google.maps.event.trigger(weekly_map, 'resize');
                    current_map.setCenter(currentLocation);
                    daily_map.setCenter(currentLocation);
                    weekly_map.setCenter(currentLocation);
                });
            }); //$.get()
        };
        window.onload = loadMap;
    .row
      .col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
        .panel.with-nav-tabs.panel-default
            .panel-heading#with-tabs
                .navbar-text Location
                ul.nav.nav-tabs
                    li.active
                        a(href='#tab1loc', data-toggle='tab') Current
                    li
                        a(href='#tab2loc', data-toggle='tab') Daily
                    li
                        a(href='#tab3loc', data-toggle='tab') Weekly
            .panel-body
                .tab-content
                    #tab1loc.tab-pane.fade.in.active
                        div(id='current_map_'+item, class='map')
                    #tab2loc.tab-pane.fade
                        div(id='daily_map_'+item, class='map')
                    #tab3loc.tab-pane.fade
                        div(id='weekly_map_'+item, class='map')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding function loadMap for every item in elders so once the page has loaded only the last function loadMap is executed.

A way around this could be to add the functions to array. Something like:

```
var loader = [];

var loadMap = function(){
     var username = "#{item}";
     // rest of your code
}
loader.push(loadMap);
```

once the loop (item in elders) is done call each function

```
while(loader.length){
    var fn = loader.pop();
    fn();
    // or even shorter 
    // loader.pop()();
}
```